# Violating use of information in time-series forecasting

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am trying to forecast stock market returns using a rolling time frame.
I want to fit a model on a 20 (trading-) day period and then `predict` one step ahead - the 21st day. I measure the error as the difference between my prediction and the actual value (simplifying things here).
[This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20725/rolling-analysis-with-out-of-sample) is the most similar question I could find which makes me think I have done something incorrectly.

I'm having problems getting straight in my head which data I am allowed to use for the modelling step and the prediction step. I think what I might have done it to use information that would (technically) be unavailable to me in a real-world implementation. Can somewhere explain the

I have provided a complete example below to show what I have been doing. Is there an error at the point that I make my prediction, where I am using information from, say tomorrow, to predict tomorrow's outcome?
I have naïvely used the `createTimeSlices` function from the {caret} package, but am now thinking I should have also shifted my outcomes column up by 1, before performing any modelling/predictions...

```
## Packages
library(quantmod)
library(xts)
library(data.table)

## Get data for Dow Jones, S&P500 and Apple
getSymbols(c("DJIA", "GSPC", "AAPL"))

## Create the log-returns
dow <- DJIA["20130111/20150914"][,6]    #extract the adjusted returns
dow <- diff(log(dow))                   #create the log returns
dow <- dow[2:672,]                      #remove first NA element
## Same for GSPC and AAPL
sp500 <- GSPC["20130114/20150914"][,6]  #extract the adjusted returns
sp500 <- diff(log(sp500))               #create the log returns
sp500 <- sp500[2:672,]                  #remove first NA element
apple <- AAPL["20130114/20150914"][,6]  #extract the adjusted returns
apple <- diff(log(apple))               #create the log returns
apple <- apple[2:672,]                  #remove first NA element

## Create a data table with all three, keeping a date column - and view it
print(my_data <- data.table(as.data.table(dow), sp500, apple))
##           index DJIA.Adjusted GSPC.Adjusted AAPL.Adjusted
##   1: 2013-01-14   0.001399526   0.004024253  -0.032057998
##   2: 2013-01-15   0.002038986   0.018994382   0.040670461
##   3: 2013-01-16  -0.001749544   0.015202322  -0.006760648
##   4: 2013-01-17   0.002696300  -0.006486296  -0.005345707
##   5: 2013-01-18   0.007500031   0.015071383   0.009494758
##  ---                                                     
## 667: 2015-09-04  -0.016774031   0.004864994   0.027441025
## 668: 2015-09-08   0.023949547   0.013681170  -0.019419791
## 669: 2015-09-09  -0.014604031  -0.010201765   0.021732156
## 670: 2015-09-10   0.004715829   0.003895656   0.014463601
## 671: 2015-09-11   0.006268550   0.005822433   0.009585282

slices <- createTimeSlices(my_data$DJIA.Adjusted,      #essentially supplying time-series length
                           initialWindow = 20,         #20-day frame
                           horizon = 1,                #predict one step ahead only
                           fixedWindow = TRUE)         #rolling frame of fixed size

## Have a look at the train and test sets
str(slices, list.len = 5)

## List of 2
##  $ train:List of 651
##   ..$ Training001: int [1:20] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
##   ..$ Training002: int [1:20] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ...
##   ..$ Training003: int [1:20] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 ...
##   ..$ Training004: int [1:20] 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 ...
##   ..$ Training005: int [1:20] 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 ...
##   .. [list output truncated]
##  $ test :List of 651
##   ..$ Testing001: int 21
##   ..$ Testing002: int 22
##   ..$ Testing003: int 23
##   ..$ Testing004: int 24
##   ..$ Testing005: int 25
##   .. [list output truncated]

## ================================= ##
##  Fit models and make predictions  ##
## ================================= ##
## Create data table to store results (we'll make 10 predictions)
results <- data.table(actual = rep(0, 10), prediction = rep(0, 10), error = rep(0, 10))

## Use a for-loop to work through all the sets (10 is enough)
for(i in 1:10) {

    ## Model used isn't important - use lm()
    my_fit <- lm(DJIA.Adjusted ~  GSPC.Adjusted + AAPL.Adjusted,
                 my_data[slices$train[[i]]]) #provide rows 1:20

    my_pred <- predict(my_fit, newdata = my_data[slices$test[[i]]])
    real_value <- my_data$DJIA.Adjusted[slices$test[[i]]]
    my_error <- real_value - my_pred

    ## Assign to results
    results$actual[i] <- real_value
    results$prediction[i] <- my_pred
    results$error[i] <- my_error

}

## Combine and inspect
print(my_output <- as.xts(cbind(my_data$index[1:10], results)))
##                   actual    prediction         error
## 2013-01-14  0.0033912188  0.0011792448  0.0022119740
## 2013-01-15 -0.0025562857  0.0021618213 -0.0047181071
## 2013-01-16 -0.0006810993  0.0009277869 -0.0016088862
## 2013-01-17  0.0005988248  0.0008679029 -0.0002690781
## 2013-01-18  0.0038483346  0.0061939031 -0.0023455685
## 2013-01-22 -0.0077337632  0.0010042278 -0.0087379909
## 2013-01-23 -0.0033745466 -0.0006517499 -0.0027227968
## 2013-01-24  0.0086044343  0.0026341100  0.0059703242
## 2013-01-25 -0.0155772387 -0.0017427651 -0.0138344736
## 2013-01-28  0.0083773576  0.0006795398  0.0076978177

## Plot results
matplot(x = my_data$index[1:10], y = results, type = c("l"), col = 1:4)
legend("bottomleft", legend = names(results), col = 1:4, pch = 24)
```

Comment: You seem to know that it's useless to use future information to predict the future. Consequently, it's difficult to determine what you are actually asking.  Could you clarify?  (It seems like you're requesting a code review, but that's not on topic here.)

Comment: @whuber - Because I created log-returns (and also include lagged variables in my actual model) I am confused as to which time period is technically the future in my model. I just want to know if I am indeed making the mistake I fear, and what the technical name for it is... what should I read about or where can I find a good example of how to achieve my goal?

Comment: @whuber - would you recommend posting this on Stack Overflow? I see it more as a statistical problem/misunderstanding than a code review.